# How can I get all HTML tags that contains certain text using regular expressions?

Tags: c#, regex, text, tags, contains

I'm new to regex and I'm not able to do what I need.

Let's suppose we have this text:

```
<h1>Título</h1>
<h2>Los gatos felices</h2>
Existen una serie de gatos...
<h2 style="color:red" class="grande">los gatos: curiosidades</h2>
<p style='text-align: justify;' align='justify'>De por si 
<strong>los gatos</strong> saben saltar y además 
<strong>los perros odian a los gatos</strong>
</p>
```

And I need to get all tags that contains the "los gatos" text.

It should match 4 coincidences:

```
- <h2>Los gatos felices</h2>

- <h2 style="color:red" class="grande">los gatos: curiosidades</h2>

- <strong>los gatos</strong>

- <strong>los perros odian a los gatos</strong>
```

How can I solve it with a regular expression?

Edit:

I finally found what I need! I share it for anyone who might need it:

```
<(.*)([^<]*)>([^<]*)los gatos([^<]*)<\/\1>
```

Comment: You [do NOT solve this with a regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3764814) - use a HTML parser. Try AngleSharp for instance.

Comment: Hi, First of all, this question is not duplicated. What I need is not to get <h2> tags. I need to get all tags that contains "los gatos" text. In this case would be <h2> tags, but may be more tags like <h3>, <strong>...

Comment: @Dalamar, Lucas is right - regular expressions are not the right tool to parse HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Regex use a real Html parser like [HtmlAgilityPack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

```
var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(yourhtmlstring);

var h2s = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h2").Select(x => x.InnerText).ToList();
```

Comment: First of all, this question is not duplicated.

Comment: Gah, the rudeness of some people in the face of decent help! Upvoted, in lieu of the OP doing so...